# Tensorflow hub fine-tune and evaluate

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I want to use tensorflow hub, to retrain one of its modules in my graph and then use that module, but my problem is when I set `trainable = True` and `tags = {"train"}` to create the module, I can not do an evaluation because of batch normalization layers.
so as I read about this issue, I found that I should create also another graph for evaluation without setting `tags = {"train"}`. but I don't know how to restore variables from train graph into eval graph. I tried creating both modules with the same name and use `reuse = True` in the eval graph, but it wasn't helpful.

Comment: I believe the same question has been asked at a later time and answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117039/tensorflow-hub-fine-tune-and-evaluate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the Solution referenced by Arno in Answer Section (even though it is present in Comments Section), for the benefit of the community.

Answer is:

With `hub.Module` for TF1, the situation is as you say: either the training or the inference graph is instantiated, and there is no good way to import both and share variables between them in a single tf.Session. That's informed by the approach used by Estimators and many other training scripts in TF1 (esp. distributed ones): there's a training Session that produces checkpoints, and a separate evaluation Session that restores model weights from them. (The two will likely also differ in the dataset they read and the preprocessing they perform.)

With TF2 and its emphasis on Eager mode, this has changed. TF2-style Hub modules (as found at https://tfhub.dev/s?q=tf2-preview) are really just [TF2-style SavedModels](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20181116-saved-model.md), and these don't come with multiple graph versions. Instead, the **call** function on the restored top-level object takes an optional training=... parameter if the train/inference distinction is required.

With this, TF2 should match your expectations. See the interactive demo [tf2_image_retraining.ipynb](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_image_retraining.ipynb) and the underlying code in [tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py) for how it can be done. The TF Hub team is working on making more complete selection of modules available for the TF2 release.