# Tensorflow Hub: Fine-tune and evaluate

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

Let's say that I want to fine tune one of the Tensorflow Hub image feature vector modules. The problem arises because in order to fine-tune a module, the following needs to be done:

```
module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/3", trainable=True, tags={"train"})
```

Assuming that the module is `Resnet50`.

In other words, the module is imported with the `trainable` flag set as `True` and with the `train tag`. Now, in case I want to validate the model (perform inference on the validation set in order to measure the performance of the model), I can't switch off the batch-norm because of the `train tag` and the `trainable` flag.

Please note that this question has already been asked here [Tensorflow hub fine-tune and evaluate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849214/tensorflow-hub-fine-tune-and-evaluate) but no answer has been provided.

I also raised a [Github issue about it](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/336) issue about it.

Looking forward to your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `hub.Module` for TF1, the situation is as you say: either the training or the inference graph is instantiated, and there is no good way to import both and share variables between them in a single tf.Session. That's informed by the approach used by Estimators and many other training scripts in TF1 (esp. distributed ones): there's a training Session that produces checkpoints, and a separate evaluation Session that restores model weights from them. (The two will likely also differ in the dataset they read and the preprocessing they perform.)

With TF2 and its emphasis on Eager mode, this has changed. TF2-style Hub modules (as found at https://tfhub.dev/s?q=tf2-preview) are really just [TF2-style SavedModels](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20181116-saved-model.md), and these don't come with multiple graph versions. Instead, the `__call__` function on the restored top-level object takes an optional `training=...` parameter if the train/inference distinction is required.

With this, TF2 should match your expectations. See the interactive demo [tf2_image_retraining.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_image_retraining.ipynb) and the underlying code in [tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py) for how it can be done. The TF Hub team is working on making more complete selection of modules available for the TF2 release.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So, in the current setup, what would be the right approach? Should I import the module in `train` mode, upon fine-tuning save it and then load it to perform evaluation? Wouldn't that import the module in `train` mode yet and again? Thanks!

Comment: `hub.Module.export()` writes all the different graph versions found in the module spec, not just the on that happened to be instantiated. So, yes, you can use this to save the module's re-trained version for eval and other uses.

The more common way is to rebuild the eval version of the model from scratch (using the original name in hub.Module) and then initialize it from a training checkpoint. That will put the training results into both the module and the model parts around it.

Comment: Thanks Arno. In the end I decided to go back to `TF Slim` for now. In that sense I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258287/reproduce-tensorflow-hub-module-output-with-tensorflow-slim) which is related to the one that you helped me with. Please have a look if you can.